# Android App: Convert 3gp to mp3

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ffmpeg, mp3

My soundfiles should be changed from 3gp to mp3.

I've tried to do this with ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.3gp -vn -acodec libmp3lame -ab 64k output.mp3
```

But the new mp3 file is only 0 KB big.

Could libmp3lame be the problem? 
Is it even possible to do that in Java?(since I only found c++ examples)

Comment: you can do this in java also

Comment: You need to include the complete `ffmpeg` console output. Otherwise we can only guess and that is inefficient.